# How to read any facebook user public timeline using iOS Social framework?

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-ios-sdk

I really have spend hours to try to solve this question unsuccesfuly!
I just want to be able to read any user's timeline (public messages) from facebook...
Technically (for simplicity) I would prefer to only use frameworks from the iOS sdk (ie. not having to use the facebook one). Therefore I currently only use Social.framework and Accounts.framework

What I've succeed to do so far is to read the facebook timeline of the currently logged user (the one identified on the device) BUT when I try to sustitute the "me" by "ANOTHER_USER_ID" in the following url @"https://graph.facebook.com/me/feed" it only returns an empty data field (no "message" node).

The "strange" fact is that I can successfully reach any feed of corporate type (like "cocacola" for exemple) using @"https://graph.facebook.com/cocacola/feed".

So my question is how to reach the feed of a "simple" user (for exemple "shireesh.asthana"), so that I can read it's "message"?

My process so far :

1. Create an app on https://developers.facebook.com/ to get an AppID
2. Use this AppID in my code to be able to send request using SLRequest

Below is the code I'm currently using :

```
ACAccountStore *account = [[ACAccountStore alloc] init];
    ACAccountType *accountType = [account
                                  accountTypeWithAccountTypeIdentifier:ACAccountTypeIdentifierFacebook];

    // Specify App ID and permissions
    NSDictionary *options = @{
                              ACFacebookAppIdKey: @"1111111111111", // My AppID here
                              //ACFacebookPermissionsKey: @[@"read_stream"],
                              ACFacebookPermissionsKey: @[@"email", @"read_stream"],
                              ACFacebookAudienceKey:ACFacebookAudienceFriends
                              };

    [account requestAccessToAccountsWithType:accountType
                                     options:options completion:^(BOOL granted, NSError *error)
     {
         if (granted == YES)
         {
             NSArray *arrayOfAccounts = [account
                                         accountsWithAccountType:accountType];

             if ([arrayOfAccounts count] > 0)
             {
                 ACAccount *facebookAccount = [arrayOfAccounts lastObject];

                 // I want the messages and the author
                 NSDictionary *parameters = @{@"fields": @"message,from"};

                 NSURL *feedURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://graph.facebook.com/HERE_THE_USER_ID/feed"]; // Work with "cocacola" but not with "shireesh.asthana"

                 SLRequest *getRequest = [SLRequest
                                           requestForServiceType:SLServiceTypeFacebook
                                           requestMethod:SLRequestMethodGET
                                           URL:feedURL 
                                           parameters:parameters];

                 getRequest.account = facebookAccount;

                 [getRequest performRequestWithHandler:
                  ^(NSData *responseData, NSHTTPURLResponse
                    *urlResponse, NSError *error)
                  {
                      dataSource = [NSJSONSerialization
                                    JSONObjectWithData:responseData
                                    options:NSJSONReadingMutableLeaves
                                    error:&error];

                      // Reach the main queue to process result
                      dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                          NSLog(@"Read %d messages", [dataSource[@"data"] count]);
                          if ([dataSource[@"data"] count] != 0) {
                              // Do stuff in case of success...
                          } else {
                              // Do stuff in case of ERROR...
                          }
                      });
                  }];
             } else {
                 // Case of no facebook account on the device...
             }
         } else {
             // User don't grant the app to access its facebook info...
         }
     }];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> So my question is how to reach the feed of a "simple" user (for exemple "shireesh.asthana"), so that I can read it's "message"?

The reason could be -

1. The `<user>` has no public posts,
2. The `<user>` has **Turn off Platform** in the [App Settings](https://www.facebook.com/settings?tab=applications&section=opt_out&view)

(of-course, the `<user>` here is not the user in session)

P.S. Shireesh Asthana (who works at Facebook), don't have any public posts

Comment: thanks for your post. About the feed of "Shireesh Asthana" I was refering to its own post : http://stackoverflow.com/a/14188483/1749367 but you are totaly right since now there is no public message on its feed.